# How can i get the URL from an image in that situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a full background slideshow, and now I am trying to build a loading script.

I will have check if the images are already loaded, but to do that I need the image URL.

The problem is that I am adding and removing classes to show the images:

```
#resp-background.back1 {
    background: url('../img/backgrounds/background1.png');
}

#resp-background.back2 {
    background: url('../img/backgrounds/background2.png');
}

#resp-background.back3 {
    background: url('../img/backgrounds/background3.png');
}
```

And i'm using a JQuery script to slide the images, just like that:

```
if (i == 2) {
  $("body, #resp-background").addClass('back1');
    $("body, #resp-background").removeClass('back2 back3');
    $(".s-description").text('Description number One'); //Put your description here

}
```

And now i am trying to get the URL using that way:

```
var bg = $("#resp-background").css("background-image")
bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
alert(bg);
```

But it doesn't work, even when I try to get the Class, i get the same message on the alert box:  Undefined.

```
var bg = $(".back1").css("background-image")
bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
alert(bg);
```

I have to remove the classes to get the URL, but thats not what i want to do.

What do i do to recognize the URL?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say that bulding a slideshow with background images set in CSS isn't a very good idea, and has it's limits. That's why all the slideshow plugins use image elements, it's a lot easier to access and control

Comment: I know that, but i already made the Slideshow, it was my mistake but i will have work on it.

Comment: also be a lot simpler with an array of the images and a position counter to access array index for switching. Wouldn't need any regex that way

Comment: Oooh, thank you, i will do a new slideshow, i did a desnecessary giant code, i will user arrays.